# Change Firefox suggestion prevalence in address bar

Tags: firefox, debian

I am using Firefox Quantum (61.0.2). When I write "server" in my address bar, the first suggestion is "server-docs.example.com" and the second is "server-staging.example.com". I would prefer that the staging server was the first suggestion so that I just have to write "server" and then hit enter, as I currently go to the staging server more often. Is there any way to manually change the order the addresses are suggested?

Comment: On firefox 57 and older (and I assume on newer too) the ranking is based on how frequently you open a site. If I want to achieve something like you want I simply open the page I want to be on the top like ten times in a row so it moves to the top.

Comment: When I check the history, the visit count for the page I want to have at the top actually is higher than the one that goes to the top, so your suggestion does not work for me.